# MediaWiki Redirects: Show URL of destination page

Tags: apache, url, mediawiki

I'm trying to figure out how to configure MediaWiki to show the destination URL after a redirect.

For example, I have page Test1 that redirects to page Test2.  When I visit Test1 by going to /wiki/Test1, I see the contents of page Test2 (including the little "Redirected from" text), but my URL still shows /wiki/Test1.  I would like this to show /wiki/Test2 instead.

I know this is possible, because Wikipedia does it.  For example, the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gases redirects to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas and the URL shown (after everything loads) is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas

Comment: FWIW, the redirect from `/Greenhouse_gases` to `/Greenhouse_gas` only works with JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour change is recent on Wikipedia (beginning of September 2014). It is currently available in the [development version of MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download_from_Git) and will be available in MediaWiki 1.24 (indeed in JavaScript because of redirections to fragments).

If you want to read more about the two competing behaviours, see the [bug 35045](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35045) and linked bugs.